# Eclipse MAT doesn't show shallow/retained heap size

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I'm trying to find a possible memory leak using the Eclipse Memory analyzer, but when I search for some objects, I cannot get the heap size for it and the columns "Shallow Heap/Retained Heap" are always empty.

[image]

When I right click on any object and do "Calculate Precise Retained Size", nothing happens. Is there something I need to run before I'm able to see some data? I see the retained heap size in histogram, but nowhere else(like in dominator tree).

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. IIRC correctly, I was able to get the data using JVisualVM.

Comment: The similar issue is happening to me as well. In my case I can find the retained heap size in dominator tree, but not in histogram. Upvoting the question for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I set preference → Memory Analyzer → Bytes Display to KB and it showed retained heap.